# CollectionViewCell keeps properties of old cell when reused

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with several cells. At time properties of views inside the `UICollectionViewCell` change. I noticed that when one of the cells is reused the "new" cell "inherits" these changed properties from the old cell – even though they are set to their initial state in the initializer of the cell.

This is happening with AutoLayout Constraints posed on Views inside the Cell and the alpha property of views (things like the text of a `UILabel` and the image of a `UIImageView` are changing exactly like they should).

Is this common behavior or is there something wrong with my code? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: This sounds like the expected behaviour as cells are re-used and the `init` is only called once. You need to implement `prepareForReuse` in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass to reset the `UICollectionViewCell` to it's default state. Then set properties on your cell in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and have the property setters in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass change the cell appropriately.

Comment: That sounds like what I have been looking for, thank you! What I still don’t get is why is one property (like the `.text` of a `UILabel`) changed but another one (like the `.alpha` of a `UIView`) isn’t?

Comment: No idea - I would have to go over your code to see what you're doing. Basically, implement my Apple-approved solution above and come back with a question with code if you run into any difficulties.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this.? In my case texts are getting updated but not the constraints

Comment: I did implement the `prepareForReuse()` function in the Cell, where I reset all the vars that had changed to their initial value but also saved the changed value in the Cell’s data. I also created a function that would set those vars again without an animation. In the Delegate before reusing the Cells I’d check their data if the vars had changed from the initial value. If so, then I’d call the function and set the vars based on the Cell’s data.